Handling struts error even after adding a new dependency
Since I've upgraded from Spring 5.x to 6.X, the jakarta ee is causing the following struts 1.3 related things to break in struts Action class.
no suitable method found for saveErrors(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages)method org.apache.struts.action.Action.saveErrors(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages) is not applicable (argument mismatch; jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be converted to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

For example, if I'm using it like this in my code, it keeps on throwing the above error for saveErrors:
public ActionForward pdf(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String type = request.getParameter("type");
    ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();

    if (Utils.nullOrBlank(id)) {
        // nothing to view
        errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("record.noId"));
        saveErrors(request, errors);
        return mapping.findForward("home");
    }

Things I tried:
I was looking at this thing and found a dependency for the same and tried adding it to my existing dependencies but that didn't help. Is there anything wrong I'm doing or if I'm heading in wrong direction, please let me know.
More details on what I tried:
Here are the dependencies I had initially:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-el</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beangle.jakarta</groupId>
        <artifactId>beangle-jakarta-dwr</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

I made the following changes to the above dependencies in the pom.xml

Replaced the group ID org.apache.struts in all of them with io.github.weblegacy

Replaced the version in all of them with 1.5.0-RC2


After the changes, here's how it is looking now:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.weblegacy</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.weblegacy</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-el</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.weblegacy</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.weblegacy</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beangle.jakarta</groupId>
        <artifactId>beangle-jakarta-dwr</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

However, it still didn't work and I ran into following issues with many classes. Here's an example of one class and the issues I encountered:
package com.checking.web;


import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;



public class UploadAction extends DispatchAction {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UploadAction.class);

    public ActionForward init(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        //some code
        return mapping.findForward("init");
    }


    public ActionForward parseForm(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();

        saveErrors(request, errors);
        return mapping.findForward("edit");
    }


    public ActionForward upload(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ActionMessages errors = new ActionMessages();


        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            saveErrors(request, errors);
            return mapping.findForward("edit");
        }

        long globalStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();



        errors.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("upload.complete"));
        saveMessages(request, errors);
        return mapping.findForward("home");
    }

    public ActionForward unspecified(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        return init(mapping, form, request, response);
    }

The errors I can see in eclipse are on the folowing lines:

For import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;

Error Description from Eclipse:
The import org.apache.struts.actions cannot be resolved
Console says: package org.apache.struts.actions does not exist on the same line

Following line for DispatchAction:
public class UploadAction extends DispatchAction {


Error Description from Eclipse:
DispatchAction cannot be resolved to a type
Console says: cannot find symbol

Line where following is used:
saveErrors(request, errors);

Error Description from Eclipse:
The method saveErrors(HttpServletRequest, ActionMessages) is undefined for the type UploadAction

Line where saveMessages(request,errors); is used:

Error Description from Eclipse:
The method saveMessages(HttpServletRequest, ActionMessages) is undefined for the type UploadAction
I wonder why other imports with org.apache.struts.action are working even though I got rid of org.apache.struts.action from the dependency and it's only complaining
for DispatchAction.

afaik Struts only works for JavaEE and not JakartaEE. Especially that old of a version. The WebLegacy version should work BUT your project is borked. You included spring-struts which has been removed long ago and isn't supported anymore (removed in Spring 4, and it won't work with Spring 6). Why is the JakartaEE 8 dependency in there, you need 9 or up. I also highly doubt spring-modules-validation still is compatible with Spring 6 but your JSTL version is certainly not JakartaEE 9 compatible.

I see. afaik Struts only works for JavaEE and not JakartaEE If you happen to find any documentation, please let me know.  I recently started the migration process so I might have used old version of JakartaEE, I will upgrade it to JakartaEE 9 or up for Spring 6. spring-struts has been there for very long time so I might try to remove that and see how it goes. Yes, I need to get rid of that JSTL version as well. Thanks!

am I doing anything wrong in terms of using web legacy version?

You should never mix jars from different versions of Spring, so the fact that there is no spring-struts for newer versions is a clear indication you are using outdated software libraries.

Yeah, I will get rid of spring-struts completely. Not sure why it has been left over there.
It could be that the person who upgraded Spring to 4 and later 5 might have not removed it. Hopefully removing that shouldn't break anything as my current version is 5.X. Could you share any documentation where I could read about spring-struts getting removed? I would like to read more about it. All I could find is the maven URL: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-struts/3.2.18.RELEASE .
